# Overloading Class Methods vs. Templates

Tags: c++

I'm looking for an elegant way (defined by minimal repeated code) to overload an operator to do the following:

I have a template class `BaseSignal` which overloads the `+=` operator, and I would like to be able to accept many different types. For example, for a double, the code looks like

```
  template <class T>
  class BaseSignal
  {
    public:
    ....
    // Self-increment
    BaseSignal<T>& operator+=(const double& rhs)
    {
      T rval;
      this->Get(&rval);
      this->Set(rval + static_cast<T>(rhs));
      return *this;
    }
    ....
```

What I've been doing is repeating this body of code for int, long, etc. Since the value `rhs` is only used in the line `static_cast<T>(rhs)`, I am repeating code while only changing the input parameter type.

So I could template this, e.g.

```
  template <class T, class U>
  class BaseSignal
  {
    public:
    ....
    // Self-increment
    BaseSignal<T>& operator+=(const U& rhs)
    {
      T rval;
      this->Get(&rval);
      this->Set(rval + static_cast<T>(rhs));
      return *this;
    }
    ....
```

But then it looks like I lose the "overloading" aspect in that the compiler would automatically select the correct method for me (it would also only work for the original `U` type that was instantiated).

I realize that I am trying to achieve some untyped language behavior with C++, which may not be the smartest thing, I am just trying to add some intelligence to a few commonly-used classes so that subsequent code will become much easier to write.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you make the operator a template?

Comment: Depending on your version on C++, you could use a `std::any`

Comment: @Chipster and how would you *conveniently* get the value out from that again?

Comment: @Aconcagua good point. That's s fair criticism.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'd have to cast it anyway when I got it out, right? Also I'm stuck at C++14...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do

```
template <class T>
class BaseSignal
{
public:

    // Self-increment
    template <class U>
    BaseSignal<T>& operator+=(const U& rhs)
    {
        T rval;
        this->Get(&rval);
        this->Set(rval + static_cast<T>(rhs));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Am I correct that you are defining a function template (which happens to be a method of a class)? In this case, how would I use this templated operator?

I read [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26631/Using-C-templates-for-functions-and-operators] and [http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/] and it's not clear when I have to declare the class in angle brackets when used.

For example, if I have a template function, I need to do `x = sum<int>(10,20);`. For the overloaded operator, won't I need a `<Type>` in there too somewhere, e.g. `signal +=<double> foo;`

Comment: If template can be deduced (which is the case here), you don't need to manually provide them. `x = sum(10,20)` is valid.same for `BaseSignal<float> sig; sig += 4.2f;`. No need to write (ugly) `sig.operator +=<float>(4.2f);`.